# Node randomly crashing without logs

Tags: cassandra, system-administration

We have a 7 Node Cluster working on Cassandra 3.9. Currently we are facing problems with 3 Nodes randomly crashing without any notes in the logs. Neither the kernel.log nor the system.log/debug.log from Cassandra contains any hints of why the node crashed.

The only thing we see is stacked up compaction jobs which never get calculated:

`pending tasks: 139
- chatlog.master_id: 1
- chatlog.reports: 1
- qsg.stats: 21
- hardcore.stats_archive: 1
- hardcore.stats: 1
- quickbedwars.stats_archive: 1
- quickbedwars.stats: 1
- permission.entity: 1
- pvp.invsave: 1
- pvp.u_match_count: 1
- conquest.leavebuster: 1
- molecraft.stats_archive: 1
- molecraft.achievement: 1
- clanwar.matches: 1
- clanwar.recent_matches_clans: 1
- network.version_logins: 1
- skywars.stats: 60
- system_traces.sessions: 1
- cores.stats: 1
- system.local: 1
- endergames.stats_archive: 1
- endergames.stats: 1
- endergames.kits: 1
- gungame.stats: 1
- system_schema.dropped_columns: 1
- system_schema.types: 1
- system_schema.tables: 1
- system_schema.indexes: 1
- system_schema.keyspaces: 1
- system_schema.columns: 1
- bedwars.stats: 26
- survivalgames.stats_archive: 1
- coinsystem.rarity_probabilities: 1
- nicksystem.texture_cache: 1
- speed_suhc.stats_archive: 1`

All stats tables are Leveld rest is SCTS

nodetool status looks like this when a node crashes:

`UN  79.133.61.x  73.63 GiB  256          ?       e5d40b71-91aa-4fb4-a883-163dfd4ddc1e  01
UN  79.133.61.x  89.85 GiB  256          ?       6f74c956-8300-4f83-82d4-eb31d5678696  01
UN  79.133.61.x  113.33 GiB  512          ?       e73560f5-d6e7-4504-9a71-52f357b3ce0f  01
UJ  79.133.61.x  29.94 GiB  512          ?       b6ff57be-393a-4cbd-b92f-3b04ac5132da  01
UN  79.133.61.x  68.11 GiB  256          ?       b9e6207e-987f-4393-bdfe-5c440e886500  01
UN  79.133.61.x  76.11 GiB  256          ?       455d53f6-23dd-45ba-9a29-9fc7b0303fc2  01
DN  79.133.61.x  95.99 GiB  256          ?       f2d3ecb1-4610-414b-b5c6-3129d96e4bc0  01`

We drained the one node which is currently joining and did a full reset of that node to start fresh.

We tried setting the compaction_throughput higher but that did not help at all. We use 4 SSDs in JBOD with 12 Core (HT) CPUs on Baremetal Servers connected with an internal 10 Gbit/s interface. We never hit any kind of resource restrictions, the I/Os look ok, memory seems fine and the CPU is not overloaded.

// Edit:

A htop screen of one node with stacked compaction tasks shows that all of the concurrent compaction threads are working on something:

[Htop output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wyqrl.png)

Dstat output looks like this:

[Dstat output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO7dx.png)

So it seems to write some chunks of data every now and then. But nothing i would consider a write load for a compaction.

I currently observed that the last log output before the node crashes is always this:

`INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2016-11-22 14:59:38,532 IndexSummaryRedistribution.java:75 - Redistributing index summaries`

// More Edit:

Running SJK shows extreme memory allocations coming out of the Compaction Threads:

```
heap allocation rate 5984mb/s
[000055] user=93.91% sys= 1.20% alloc= 1292mb/s - CompactionExecutor:2
[000056] user=94.85% sys= 0.21% alloc= 1142mb/s - CompactionExecutor:3
[000057] user=94.85% sys=-0.01% alloc= 1135mb/s - CompactionExecutor:4
[000054] user=97.10% sys=-0.03% alloc= 1084mb/s - CompactionExecutor:1
```

GC logs show normal numbers (using GCG1 with 26GB Heap as Als Cassandra tunning suggests trying):

```
[Parallel Time: 8.9 ms, GC Workers: 10]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 2976069.1, Avg: 2976069.2, Max: 2976069.2, Diff: 0.1]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 2.4, Avg: 2.4, Max: 2.5, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 24.4]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 4.1, Avg: 4.3, Max: 4.5, Diff: 0.4, Sum: 42.8]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 8, Avg: 16.2, Max: 33, Diff: 25, Sum: 162]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 0.1, Avg: 0.1, Max: 0.3, Diff: 0.2, Sum: 1.4]
      [Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 1.8, Avg: 1.9, Max: 2.0, Diff: 0.2, Sum: 19.1]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
         [Termination Attempts: Min: 4, Avg: 6.0, Max: 8, Diff: 4, Sum: 60]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.1, Max: 0.1, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 0.6]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 8.8, Avg: 8.8, Max: 8.9, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 88.4]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 2976078.0, Avg: 2976078.0, Max: 2976078.0, Diff: 0.0]
   [Code Root Fixup: 0.1 ms]
   [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
   [Clear CT: 0.4 ms]
   [Other: 1.4 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 0.1 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 0.0 ms]
      [Redirty Cards: 0.1 ms]
      [Humongous Register: 0.1 ms]
      [Humongous Reclaim: 0.0 ms]
      [Free CSet: 0.8 ms]
   [Eden: 4904.0M(4904.0M)->0.0B(4904.0M) Survivors: 8192.0K->8192.0K Heap: 6880.3M(8192.0M)->1976.7M(8192.0M)]
```

Comment: Is it always the same node that dies?  Also, why is one node joining "UJ"?  Is it stuck in that state?  First, I'd work on getting that node to join properly.  Also, what kind of load is the cluster on?

Comment: The Node is joined after 6 hours. The Problem with down nodes persits even with the node joined. The Cluster has ~6k Req/s with ~80% read requests. All of them are simple SELECTs on one or two partition keys. The Nodes seem too crash due to compaction, which i don't understand.